# how to link files in node_modules laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello guys I'm trying to link a package which I have installed using npm. But I cannot link the files to my html. I have also use the asset() but it did not work. Thank you!

```
<link href="node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.css">

<script src="node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.js"></script>
```

Comment: use `https://` on `href=""` & `src=""`

Comment: You need to either user absolute URL or correct the relative URL

Comment: `asset` will not work for you in this case as `node_modules` in not in the public folder (please don't move it to the public folder). What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Hello I tried changing it with http/https not working. I am using Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can link directly to your node_modules folder

either add it in your app.scss and app.js as an import or extract it with laravel mix

In your mix

```
 mix.copy('node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.js', 'public/js')
```

In html head

```
<script src="{{ mix("js/fullpage.js") }}"></script>
```

Comment: Hello I tried putting the code to my webpack.mix.js and change the src. I'm still getting a 404.

Comment: @RenzchlerOxiño updated my answer, now using the mix helper

Comment: Also check that your files are actually in the public folder after you run npm run watch or npm run dev

Comment: It works now. I did not know about laravel mix. Thank you so much @Marcus!